# BSOD: "Critical_Service_Failed" after removing all permissions for the C: drive under security options

Tags: windows-10, boot, permissions, bsod

I removed all permissions under security for my main(C:) drive and restarted my laptop(OS:Win 10). This has led to a BSOD with a "Critical_Service_Failed" error. I would like my system back to booting condition, without having to delete files by reinstalling windows.

All attempts to resolve issue:

-So far I've tried to restore the OS to a previous point via a Win 10 recovery as well as installation USB Stick. (Unsuccessful, due to errors with all of the restore points windows has automatically created.)

-I've tried to reinstall the OS, while keeping the files. (Unsuccessfully, because the automatic option returns and error saying, that it is not possible to do this over usb. When I try to do it custom, I have to delete a partition and reformat it to NTFS, which is not an option either.)

-"sfc /scannow" (Unsuccessful, as sfc had no access to any file.)

-Attempted to take ownership of "C:" with "takeown" via cmd and then get the r/w permissions via "icacls" (Unsuccessful, as I have no privileges even in recovery mode.)

Currently I am looking into the possibility of manipulating permissions via Linux, which was already installed on the laptop for dual booting. (Although, I don't expect much from this either.)

Thank you for your helpful input.

Comment: **You performed an action that cannot be reversed.** You will have to reinstall Windows.  Is there a reason you removed permissions on a drive that were actually required?

Comment: I see, thank you. I will do that then.